# can't inject a internal interface

Tags: c#, interface

Unable to inject an interface which is internal to a service class that is public.

below is the interface which I created with the internal modifier.

```
   internal interface IDespatchTrackingNotifications
   {
     int SendConsolidatedDespatchNotifications(int days);
   }
```

this is the service I am trying to inject the interface to

```
 public class DespatchTrackingDomainService : IDespatchTrackingDomainService
 {
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;
    private readonly IShippingCarrierRepository _shippingCarrierRepository;
    private readonly IDespatchLineRepository _despatchLineRepository;
    private readonly IOrderLineRepository _orderLineRepository;
    private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;
    private readonly IDespatchTrackingNotifications _despatchTrackingNotifications;
    private readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(DespatchTrackingDomainService));

    public DespatchTrackingDomainService(
        IKernel kernel,
        IShippingCarrierRepository shippingCarrierRepository,
        IDespatchLineRepository despatchLineRepository,
        IOrderLineRepository orderLineRepository,
        ICustomerRepository customerRepository,
        IDespatchTrackingNotifications despatchTrackingNotifications)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
        _shippingCarrierRepository = shippingCarrierRepository;
        _despatchLineRepository = despatchLineRepository;
        _orderLineRepository = orderLineRepository;
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
        _despatchTrackingNotifications = despatchTrackingNotifications;
    }
```

I want to understand why the interfaces can't be public.

the above code will throw error on the service class where I am trying to inject the internal interface.

Error is:

> "Inconsistant accessability, parameter type DespatchTrackingNotifications is lessa accessable then DespatchTrackingDomainService.

Comment: Do you get a syntax error or run time exception?

Comment: Because the class is public. It's part of the constructor of a public class and the internal class is less accessible which is exactly the reason why.

Comment: yes the class is public, I get compile time error.
Point of creating the internal interface is so that this can be used only in the assembly as currently it is used in this particular service.

Comment: You're using an internal interface in a public constructor. Public means that methods outside the assembly can call the constructor and instantiate your class. But how can they do that when they need to pass an internal interface?